# jQuery delegated function being fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamically generated html that I add to the DOM when my page loads, the HTML looks like so and there are many instances of this (think of a grid):

```
<div class="qty">
<input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-price="2.99" 
   data-product="Something" value="2">
<div class="control-wrapper">
<span class="increment"> + </span> 
<span class="decrement"> - </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I have a function that increments or decrements the value of the input in my scripts, like so:

```
$('#identifier').on('click', '.increment', changeVal);
$('#identifier').on('click', '.decrement', changeVal);

function changeVal(event) {
        if(event.target.attributes['class'].value === 'increment') {
            $(event.target).closest('.qty').find('input')[0].value++;
        } else if (event.target.attributes['class'].value === 'decrement') {
            $(event.target).closest('.qty').find('input')[0].value--;
        }
    }
```

Now I also have a function that listens for the change event on the input and performs a number of calculations, like so...

```
$('#identifier').on('change', '.quantity-input', updateItemTotal);

function updateItemTotal(event) {

// do stuff

}
```

Now this is great if the user manually changes the value of the input via typing but should they change the value via the `changeVal` function the `updateItemTotal` isn't fired when the input value changes. What event could I add to the `$('#identifier').on('change', '.quantity-input', updateItemTotal);` when the user involks the `changeVal(event`) function

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move your calculation logic to a separate function and call this function from both events.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeVal(event) {
  if(event.target.attributes['class'].value === 'increment') {
    $(event.target).closest('.qty').find('input')[0].value++;
  } 
  else if (event.target.attributes['class'].value === 'decrement') {
     $(event.target).closest('.qty').find('input')[0].value--;
  }

  // can you just put the function call here?
  updateItemTotal();

}
```

Comment: I thought about that but I need to pass the event object into updateItemTotal(event)

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger change for the event `change` to work

```
$(event.target).closest('.qty').find('input').change()[0].value++;
```

**Note:** You can use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zma2fddr/)